# Tsql, is there a way to update row using an existing field in the row as part of a string in another field in the same row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to update rows in my sql server 2008 r2 web edition database. I need to use a field that is already in the row and concat? that field into a string in another field in the same row.

This is for a real estate database where i have a column called mlsnumber, i need to use the mlsnumber field as part of a string in another column, same row called photoname.

In this case mlsnumber =1234567, i need to add/update row so photoname=`photo`+mlsnumber+'-01.jpg'  (photo1234567-01.jpg)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Ken

Comment: i think you can use computed column for that

Answer (score 6):

assuming table is called photos

```
update photos set photoname = 'photo' + mIsnumber + '-01.jpg'
```

if misnumber is not a varchar you could do

```
update photos set photoname = 'photo' + cast(mIsnumber as varchar(10)) + '-01.jpg'
```

if misnumber is null then the result is null so it could be

```
update photos set photoname = 'photo' + coalesce(cast(mIsnumber as varchar(10)),'') + '-01.jpg'
```

You can also add a where clause if you wish to filter which records you update.

Additionally if this is always going to be the case you could look at using a view to retrieve the data rather than storing it in the table or alternatively using a calculated field in the table.

Answer (score 1):

```
update table1 set
   photoname = 'photo' + cast(mlsnumber as nvarchar(max)) + '-01.jpg'
where mlsnumber = 1234567
```

you also could just select this in the view:

```
create view vw_table1
as
    select
        *,
        'photo' + cast(mlsnumber as nvarchar(max)) + '-01.jpg' as photoname
    from table1
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
UPDATE  t
SET     photoname = 'photo' + CAST(misnumber AS VARCHAR(255)) + '-1.jpg'
WHERE   misnumber = 1234567;
```

If you want to do it for all rows, then just remove the `where` clause.

Comment: Also the use of `where` seems wrong - I think it should be omitted. If it were only this row, you could hardcode the photname just like you hardcoded the misnumber

Answer (score 1):

```
Update tablename set photoname = 'photo'+mlsnumber+ '-01.jpg'
```

This will update every row,  so be careful with the update. You may want to use `begin transaction`, run the query, check results and then `commit` or `rollback`, if you want to test your update statement in isolation.

If you need to convert mlsnumber, see link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx